# Scrolling a UITableView with an embedded UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I have a UITableView with a custom UITableViewCell.  The cell has a UITextField for user data entry.

I've noticed that the tableview will not scroll if the user initiates the touch on the text view.

I'm struggling with finding a way to allow the user to touch the text field to enable editing but still scroll the tableview.  Essentially, I need the text view to respond to taps but not drags, any ideas?

Comment: can you post some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't try thi way but I have an idea:

1. We do disable the textfield on cell.
2. When use selects cell (row in tableview), we will becomeFirstResponder the textfield
3. After user return from textfield, we do disable the textfield again.

Comment: That's simple and worked well!  Thanks!